# How can I cluster based on the complementary categories?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, clustering

K-means tries to find centroid and then clusters around the centroids. But what if we want to cluster based on the complement?

For example, suppose we have a group of animals and we want to cluster Dogs, Cats, (Not Dogs and Not Cats). The 3rd category will not arise from mean clustering.

Comment: generally clustering (as you examplify with k-means) requires a representation. What would *not* refer to in this space?

Comment: Why do you say that the 3rd category will not be arisen from the mean clustering? What is the 3rd category? _Not Dogs_? Btw, what do you mean by "mean clustering"? Do you mean "k-means cluster algorithm"?

Answer (score 1):

Note: K-means does not assume an interpretation/label of the clusterings - in fact it is an [unsupervised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) algorithm. The interpretations are a result of **human analysis** *after* running K-means.

For example, in the case of cats and dogs one would most definitely chose k = 2 - which provides an easy interpretation. However, what would it mean if we set k = 1000. We no longer have a "clean" interpretation of the centroids.

Note: how I keep saying "interpretation." The algorithm simply assigns a data point to a cluster and calls it a day. Humans then look at the results and try to **understand** them with an **interpretation**.

Continuing with the example where k = 2. One could easily interpret "is cat" as "not dog" and "is dog" as "not cat." The idea here is that the data is **unlabeled** beforehand and humans try to fathom the results retrospectively by assigning the resulting clusters with an understandable label.

I hope this clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of clustering is to look for the **same characteristics** in the data and group them into clusters. The number of clusters we take is based on how our **clustering algorithm evaluated**.

For example, we use the **Elbow Method** for evaluates. We take optimal number of clusters that distortion start decreasing in a linear fashion. In the picture below, the **optimal number of clusters** for the data is 3.

[image]